# Scale lowercase symbol to uppercase height

Tags: scaling

I would like to type a company name which contains a greek letter, e.g.
`Name\:$\alpha$`,
but I would like the lowercase greek symbol to be the size of a capital letter, which I have hacked using 
`Name\:\scalebox{1.6}[1.6]{$ \alpha $}`. Here are the two outputs:

[image: Outputs of company names.]

What would be a best way to achieve the desired result so that when I 'capitalise' the lowercase greek letter it is scaled to the size of an uppercase letter (maintaining its aspect ratio).

Any help would be appreciated, as I have struggled to find anything similar online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\resizebox` with the height given as the same height as a capital letter, e.g. A:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newlength{\CapLen}
\AtBeginDocument{\settoheight{\CapLen}{A}} % after \normalsize
\begin{document}
N\resizebox{!}{\CapLen}{$\alpha$}ME
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks. PS - Would I use a similar approach with `\settowidth` in the scenario I wanted to scale `\alpha` to the width of e.g. `M`?

Comment: @oliversm Yes, and swap the arguments to `\resizebox{\CapLen}{!}{$\alpha$}`.