# Inserting a special letter in LaTex

Tags: fonts, symbols, letters

A quick question: Is there a way to insert in LaTex a lowercase z, inside $$, with an additional horizontal line between the two existed parallel lines? The desired letter (symbol) looks like
[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: You could rescale the uppercase Z to an lowercase symbol:[Scale lowercase symbol to uppercase height](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/314696/124842). If your uppercase `Z` contains (three horizontal lines) this could be an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `\ooalign` to overlay a rule on the `z` in math or text mode.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\mathz}{\ooalign{$z$\cr\hfil\rule[.5ex]{.2em}{.06ex}\hfil\cr}}
\newcommand{\textz}{\ooalign{z\cr\hfil\rule[.5ex]{.2em}{.1ex}\hfil\cr}}

\begin{document}
z\textz$z\mathz$
\end{document}
```

You can adjust the length (`.2em`), height (`.5ex`) and thickness (`.06ex` in math or `.1ex` in text) of the rule to your liking. Note the `em` and `ex` units so the rule will adjust with the size of the character (e.g., using `scriptsize`).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend to use a font, that provides such a character. But if you want, you can fake it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*{\specialz}{z\kern\mbox{-}.37em-\relax}
\begin{document}
z vs. \specialz

\large z vs. \specialz

\Large z vs. \specialz

\LARGE z vs. \specialz

\huge z vs. \specialz

\Huge z vs. \specialz

\normalsize
\sffamily

z vs. \specialz

\large z vs. \specialz

\Large z vs. \specialz

\LARGE z vs. \specialz

\huge z vs. \specialz

\Huge z vs. \specialz

\normalfont\normalsize But avoid: $\specialz_{\specialz}$
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

However, this solution is font depending and the math mode should be handled separately. So again: Better use a font that provides the wanted symbol.

Comment: Nice, but what if I want the symbol inside $$? If I use $\specilaz$ then the addiitonal lines is too long.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z As I've said: It is font depending! I don't know the fonts you are using! However, use another horizontal bar, e.g., `\mbox{-}` or are `\rule` or … But better: Use a font, that provides the wanted symbol!

Comment: I don't know of any fonts that provide such symbol. Do you?

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z Do you want all lowercase z with middle line or only some?

Comment: Not all of them.

Answer (score 2):

Draw a rule across the letter, at mid height.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\cz}{% crossed z
  \mathord{\mathpalette\vaggelis@z{z}}%
}
\newcommand{\cZ}{% crossed Z
  \mathord{\mathpalette\vaggelis@z{Z}}%
}
\newcommand{\vaggelis@z}[2]{%
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1#2$}%
  \ooalign{%
    $\m@th#1#2$\cr
    \hidewidth
    \vrule height \dimexpr.5\ht\z@+0.03ex\relax
           depth -\dimexpr.5\ht\z@-0.03ex\relax
           width .5\wd\z@
    \hidewidth\cr
  }%
  \vphantom{\box\z@}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\cz+z_{\cz}<\cZ+Z_{\cZ}$

\Huge

$\cz+z_{\cz}<\cZ+Z_{\cZ}$

\end{document}
```

[image]